# for loop stops before last iteration

Tags: java, android

I've been programming an Android app which is supposed to add `TextView`s progrmatically. It is supposed to add 28 of them using a for loop. Below are the the important parts of the loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++){
        Log.i("Creating round", "" + (i + 1));
        final int j = i;
        roundLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        roundLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        roundLayout[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        roundLayout[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectRound(j);
            }
        });
        layout.addView(roundLayout[i], lp);
        TextView title = new TextView(getActivity());
        title.setText("Round " + MainActivity.intFormat(i + 1, 2));
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTextSize(20);
        title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
        roundLayout[i].addView(title, titleParams);
```

So as you can see, this loop, in each of its iterations, adds a `roundLayout` in the main `layout`, and in each of them adds a `Textview title` displaying the round number. However, while it is supposed to create 28 of them it only creates 27, but the logging goes till 28.

[image: Here's a screenshot from the app (scrolled to the bottom)]

And here's what appears in the logcat:

```
    I/Creating round: 1
    I/Creating round: 2
    I/Creating round: 3
    I/Creating round: 4
    I/Creating round: 5
    I/Creating round: 6
    I/Creating round: 7
    I/Creating round: 8
    I/Creating round: 9
    I/Creating round: 10
    I/Creating round: 11
    I/Creating round: 12
    I/Creating round: 13
    I/Creating round: 14
    I/Creating round: 15
    I/Creating round: 16
    I/Creating round: 17
    I/Creating round: 18
    I/Creating round: 19
    I/Creating round: 20
    I/Creating round: 21
    I/Creating round: 22
    I/Creating round: 23
    I/Creating round: 24
    I/Creating round: 25
    I/Creating round: 26
    I/Creating round: 27
    I/Creating round: 28
```

EDIT:
I've noticed that the container (which's width and height are set to match_parent) in which the layout is inflated may go past the screen (if that's even a thing). Have a look at the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

The first screenshot shows the uppermost element of the component tree. We can clearly see the 4 blue lines delimiting it. However, the second screenshot shows the container in which the layout is inflated and we can't see the right nor the bottom line delimiting it. Here's the code for the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/app_name">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

     </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your textView start with Round 0 ?

Comment: Nope. Goes from 1 to 27.

Comment: just add "="   for(int i = 0; i <= 28; i++) and you're good to go

Comment: Unclear. Your `for` statement loops 28 times (from 0 to 27). So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @PraveenGM That would loop 29 times! I don't think this is what OP wants!

Comment: What do you mean with you question? Your loop goes from `i = 0` until `i < 28`, more specifically `0, 1, ..., 26, 27`. the console output is always `i + 1`, so `1, 2, ..., 27, 28`.

Comment: @Praveen GM This may be a solution, but I don't think it's a good idea. First of all, the loop will iterate 29 times, creating a 29th layout (which is not desired) in a 28-layout long array. I was thinking it was more a problem with the display rather than the code itself, and am looking for a "real" solution to it.

Comment: Is there any padding to layout from the bottom? Also, instead of making it complicated by initializing `i = 0` and using `(i+1)` everywhere, just add `i=1 ; i<=28 i++`

Comment: op meant is this: `So as you can see, this loop, in each of its iterations, adds a roundLayout in the main layout, and in each of them adds a Textview title displaying the round number. However, while it is supposed to create 28 of them it only creates 27, but the logging goes till 28.`

Comment: @Kavita_p arrays require i to start at 0 anyways

Comment: The problem seems related to the view not the loop. Have you try using only one Linear Layout with vertical orientation then adding each TextView to it?

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך  Agree with the fact that it seems to come from the view. these roundLayouts are RelativeLayouts which are all added in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Have you tried to call `layout.invalidate()`? Maybe the last element is just not being drawn

Comment: @GBrandt layout.invalidate() didnt work

Comment: I think the last TextView is displayed under the screen. Is this even possible?

Comment: That should be it! You probably didn't add a scroll view as the parent layout.

Comment: The parent layout is a ScrollView

Comment: I'm thinking that the container in which the layout is inflated continues under the screen. But the container's height is set to match_parent, and the parent matches exactly the screen.

Comment: try changing the layout under the scrollview to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. And please add the related code so that I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Doesnt work with wrap_content either

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems related to the view not the loop. Here I'm reproducing the views with your code and slightly modified it.

`activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/parent_rly"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private LinearLayout[] roundLayout;
  private LinearLayout layout;
  private LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
  private LinearLayout.LayoutParams titleParams;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.parent_rly);

    roundLayout = new LinearLayout[28];
    lp= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    titleParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    addingTextViews();
  }

  private void addingTextViews() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
      Log.i("Creating round", "" + (i + 1));
      roundLayout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
      roundLayout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
      roundLayout[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

      layout.addView(roundLayout[i], lp);
      TextView title = new TextView(this);
      title.setText("Round " + (i + 1));
      title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
      title.setTextSize(20);
      title.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
      roundLayout[i].addView(title, titleParams);
    }
  }
}
```

and it show the views correctly:

[image]

Comment: The layout is not created in the MainActivity but in a fragment inflated in activity_main's container (code in the question). Its this container which seems to continue beyond the screen.